# Disable Visual Basic Err object while debugging

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception

I have a windows service written in VB.NET and for error logging at runtime it uses the [Err](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka13cy19(v=vs.90).aspx) object of Visual Basic. When I am debugging the service it is not giving me any error but at the same time it is setting the `Err` object with number `13` which means I have a type mismatch somewhere (According to [Error List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264979(v=vs.60).aspx)) Any idea how I can forcefully throw the runtime exception while debugging? I have tried commenting the below code but no luck:-

```
On Error Resume Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Err.Raise() method or Throw Err.GetException() method if Err has any error.

```
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Throw Err.GetException()
End If
```

OR

```
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Raise(Number:=Err.Number, Source:=Err.Source, Description:=Err.Description, HelpFile:=Err.HelpFile, HelpContext:=Err.HelpContext)
End If
```

Comment: But this will raise the exception not at the point at which exception actually occurred. I anyways have the exception details so Raise will not help either.

Comment: Err.GetException returns Exception, which you can use to identify the code where the mismatch is occurring and then you can handle that in a better way. btw turning on the Option Strict for vb.net project may help you in identifying the problem at compile time also.