# VB.Net Error object in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, error-handling

I don't think there is a *good* way to do this...

but I have a vb.Net DLL which has an error handling method. Its **good**, and I want to use it in my C#.Net site.

So I add the vb.Net DLL to my C# project.

But wait! My vb.Net error handler method requires a '**Microsoft.VisualBasic.ErrObject**' !

---

Hmm.. is it possible to create such a data type in C#? Even by some type of conversion?

Or is this just ugly and should I forget about even trying something so outrageous and just restart the project in vb.Net?

*note that I am **not** going to change the required data type in the DLL

Thanks!

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Any suggestions on my problem? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32800427/disabled-visual-basic-err-object-while-debugging

Answer (score 2):

You can add a reference to the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` dll to your C# project.

Right-click the `References` in the `solution explorer` click `Add Reference`,then search for `Microsoft.VisualBasic`:

[image]

[How to: Add or Remove References By Using the Add Reference Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

---

But in general i would suggest to use the .NET error handling with exceptions that inherit from or are `System.Exception` and support using [`try-catch-finally`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dszsf989.aspx).

Comment: Yes this allows you to create the object :) thank you! But to do a try-catch with this still causes a problem because you have to catch an object derived from System.Exception

Comment: @Christopher: good point, added it to my question. But OP hasn't mentioned that he wants to use `try...catch`. However, never used `VisualBasic.ErrObject` in VB.NET or C# so no idea if it works at all.

Comment: if you mean errors generated by Err.Raise vb method, such error can be  distinguished by theException.TargetSite.DeclaringType (the fact that it is System.Exception still is PITA, as written by Christopher before)